# How would you delete files with a certain string at the end of their names?

Tags: shell, delete

I have some photos named like this: `photo_1@15-05-2018_18-49-14.png`

But I only want to delete files with ending with `_thumb.png`, like p`hoto_1@15-05-2018_18-49-14_thumb.png`

**All of them are in different directories too**

How would I delete all files ending with `_thumb.png` in the Linux shell? (I can't use file explorer cause it keeps crashing; there are just thousands of files with `_thumb` in their name).

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f -name '*_thumb.png' -exec rm -f {} +
```

This would call `rm -f` on batches of regular files whose names matches the pattern `*_thumb.png`.  The files will be found in the current directory or in any of its subdirectories, or below.

If you have GNU `find`, or a `find` implementation that implements the `-delete` action (which you would likely have on Linux), you could instead use the slightly shorter

```
find . -type f -name '*_thumb.png' -delete
```

Insert `-print` before `-delete` (or `-exec`) to also get a listing of the pathnames that are removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
rm -r *_thumb.png
```

Thanks to a friend for answering that.

Comment: This would still only affect names matching that pattern in the _current_ directory.

Comment: And if you have thousands of these files, you will probably exceed the permitted size of the args to rm. Cultivate your circle of friends.